# We are level 10 clan. What now?

Tags: clash-of-clans

We are level 10 clan now in Clash of Clans.

Is there level 11? Are there any more perks? Will our clan's level increase now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Galadon, a CoC Youtuber that Supercell gives early access to some information, leveling your clan past ten is possible, as there is no limit set for clan level, however no perks for higher level clans have been released nor does Supercell has any plans to add perks for higher level clans, but they may add additional perks to clans level 1-10. Galadon talks about this on one of his youtube videos. I will try and update this with the link when I get a chance to look for it.